# Where is this event calling to in MarionetteJS

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I am exploring the BBCloneMail demo application for MarionetteJS, but I am not seeing how the events are triggering the rendering actions. I saw some global 'show' event here:

https://github.com/marionettejs/bbclonemail/blob/master/public/javascripts/bbclonemail/components/appController.js#L25

```
show: function(){
  this._showAppSelector("mail");
  Marionette.triggerMethod.call(this, "show");
},
```

But I don't see, where/how the Marionette.triggerMethod results into rendering the Mail component. I was trying to call the triggerMethod for my case, but I get a 'cannot call apply for undefined'. Why is the call above working for the BBcloneMail application.

[image: trigger Method]

The Application controller for my case:

```
MA.AppController = Marionette.Controller.extend({

  initialize: function(){
    _.bindAll(this, "_showGenres");
  },


  show: function() {
    if (MA.currentUser) {
      MA.navbar.show(new MA.Views.Items.LogoutNavbar({model: MA.currentUser}));
    }
    else
    {
      MA.navbar.show(new MA.Views.Items.LoginNavbar());
    }
    this._showGenres();
  },

  _showGenres: function() {
    var categoryNav = new MA.Navigation.Filter({
      region: MA.filter
    });
    this.listenTo(categoryNav, "genre:selected", this._categorySelected);
    categoryNav.show();
    MA.main.show(MA.composites.movies);
  },

  showMovieByGenre: function(genre){
    var movies = new MA.Controllers.MoviesLib();
    that = this;
    $.when(movies.getByCategory(genre)).then(that._showMovieList);

    Backbone.history.navigate("#movies/genres/" + genre);
  },

  _showMovieList: function(movieList){
    var moviesLib = new MA.Controllers.MoviesLib({
      region: MA.main,
      movies: movieList
    });
    Marionette.triggerMethod.call(this, "show");

  }
});
```

I init the application controller in a init.js with:

```
app = new MA.AppController();
```

Comment: Can you post your controller code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [source for `triggerMethod`](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/lib/backbone.marionette.js#L554), this is a way of both triggering an event (the string being passed in), and additionally (if it exists) running a method on the object that has an 'on' prefix.

In your case the error relates to [line 560](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/lib/backbone.marionette.js#L560), specifically that there is no method `apply` on undefined. Based on the code its (in your case) trying to call the equivilent of `this.trigger('show')` - but `AppController` doesn't have a method called `trigger`.

In which case I'm guessing that in the BBCloneMail example `this` (being bassed into `triggerMethod.call`) is not actually the controller, but instead the view that is to be shown.

Comment: This is a very helpful answer, so I accept it. Although I need to do some refactoring to get the app working now :-)